# How to get the next free item in DynamoDB in concurrent environment

Tags: java, filter, amazon-dynamodb, dbscan

I have a table in DynamoDB with my users (Partial key = key, Sort key = no):

**key**    **isActive**

user1       true

user2       false

...         ...

In my code I need to return a next user with status not active (isActive=false). What is the best way to do this, if I need solution is based on that I have

1. A huge table
2. Concurrent environment

I wrote code that works, BUT I amn't sure it is a good solution due to Scan and Filter expression:

```
public String getFreeUser() throws IOException {
        Table table = dynamoDB.getTable("usersTableName");

        ScanSpec spec = new ScanSpec()
                .withFilterExpression("isActive = :is_active")
                .withValueMap(new ValueMap().withBoolean(":is_active", false));

        ItemCollection<ScanOutcome> items = table.scan(spec);

        Iterator<Item> iterator = items.iterator();
        Item item = null;

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            item = iterator.next();
            try {
                UpdateItemSpec updateItemSpec = new UpdateItemSpec()
                        .withPrimaryKey(new PrimaryKey("key", item.getString("key")))
                        .withUpdateExpression("set #ian=:is_active_new")
                        .withConditionExpression("isActive = :is_active_old")
                        .withNameMap(new NameMap()
                                .with("#ian", "isActive"))
                        .withValueMap(new ValueMap()
                                .withBoolean(":is_active_old", false)
                                .withBoolean(":is_active_new", true))
                        .withReturnValues(ReturnValue.ALL_OLD);

                UpdateItemOutcome outcome = table.updateItem(updateItemSpec);

                return outcome.getItem().getString("key");

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }

        throw new IOException("No active users were found");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**GSI + Query == GOOD**

```
userID (PK) | isActive | otherAttribute | ...
user1       | true     | foo            | ...
user2       | false    | bar            | ...
user3       | true     | baz            | ...
user4       | false    | 42             | ...
...

GSI:
userID | isActive (GSI-PK)
user1  | true
user2  | false
user3  | true
user4  | false
```

Add a GSI with a hash key of `isActive`. This will allow you to query directly the items where `isActive` == `false`.

The benefit vs scan and filter is that reads will be much more efficient. The cost is that your GSI requires it's own storage, so if your table is huge (as per your assumption) then you might want to consider a sparse index.

**Sparse Index GSI + Query == BETTER**

```
userID (PK) | isNotActive | otherAttribute | ...
user1       |             | foo            | ...
user2       | false       | bar            | ...
user3       |             | baz            | ...
user4       | false       | 42             | ...
...

GSI:
userId | isNotActive (GSI-PK)
user2  | false
user4  | false
```

Consider replacing the attribute `isActive` with `isNotActive` and don't give this attribute to the active users. That is, the inactive users will have `true` but the active users will not have this attribute at all. You can then create your GSI with this `isNotActive` attribute. Since it only contains the inactive users, it will be smaller and more efficient to store and query.

Note that when a user becomes active you will need to delete this attribute, and vice versa for active users that become inactive.

**Attribute Projections**

Regardless of which GSI you decide is best for you, if you know which attribute(s) you will need when querying these inactive users - even if it's just "all of them" - you can project these to your GSI so that you don't need to do the second lookup by key. This will increase the size of your GSI, but may be a tradeoff worth making depending on your table size, the ratio of active to inactive users, and your expected access patterns.

**UPDATE**

In response to the first comment, to be clear the GSI key (now labelled "GSI-PK") is not the userID. I could put the `isActive` or `active` column on the far left in the GSI tables, but that's not how it appears in the AWS console so I've left it in the original order for consistency with the way AWS display it.

Re the second comment on concurrency, you're right I didn't address this. My solution will work in a concurrent environment except for one thing - you can only do eventually consistent reads, not strongly consistent reads. What this means is that a very recent newly inactive user (and by recent I mean a fraction of a second in most circumstances) might not have replicated to the GSI yet. Similarly, a user that has recently changed from inactive to active might not have updated the GSI yet. You'll need to consider whether eventually consistent reads are acceptable for your use case.

Another consideration is that if this is going to be a very large table, if the query results are going to total >1MB you're going to get a paginated result anyway because DynamoDB enforce that limit. Without a global table lock, you're going to get some inconsistency due to updates from other clients between page queries, in which case eventually consistent reads will need to work for you.

Comment: Your answer is spot on, however, the "pictures" seem to show userid as keys.  The text is correct...GSI hash key --> isNotActive, S/K --> user ID

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, what about code and concurrency issue? Will it the same as my code, I need to create index on isActive field ONLY?

Comment: @Rougher if you must have `isActive` as the attribute name, you could still make it sparse if you only set this attribute where it is `false` i.e. is inactive, and then you can infer that a user is active if it does not have `isActive` == `false`. A bit cryptic but that would work. If you need the attribute on all of them, you could also add a second `isNotActive` attribute for use by the GSI to keep it sparse. If you can only have one, then a GSI with both `true` and `false` is still much better than no index. That is, a query is more efficient than a scan.